# Why some commercial DVD do not mount?

Tags: mount, 15.04, dvd

I have installed all the required add ons -such as restricted extras, to play commercial DVDs on my Ubuntu machine, but some of them are not mounted on Ubuntu and thus unable to play.

It seems that is happening on DVDs made around 2009-10 rather than more actual movies.

Is there any way to make Ubuntu mount these DVDs?

Comment: Insert the DVD, type `dmesg -T` and you will see why the system likes/does not like your DVD